# Why does the Collection interface have equals() and hashCode()?

Tags: java, collections

Why does the [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface have `equals(Object o)` and `hashCode()`, given that any implementation will have those by default (inherited from `Object`) ?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Collection JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html):

> While
>   the `Collection` interface adds no stipulations to the general contract
>   for the `Object.equals`, programmers who implement the `Collection`
>   interface "directly" (in other words, create a class that is a
>   `Collection` but is not a `Set` or a `List`) must exercise care if they
>   choose to override the `Object.equals`. It is not necessary to do so,
>   and the simplest course of action is to rely on Object's
>   implementation, but the implementor may wish to implement a "value
>   comparison" in place of the default "reference comparison." (The `List`
>   and `Set` interfaces mandate such value comparisons.)
>
> The general contract for the `Object.equals` method states that equals
>   must be symmetric (in other words, `a.equals(b)` if and only if
>   `b.equals(a)`). The contracts for `List.equals` and `Set.equals` state that
>   lists are only equal to other lists, and sets to other sets. Thus, a
>   custom equals method for a collection class that implements neither
>   the `List` nor `Set` interface must return false when this collection is
>   compared to any list or set. (By the same logic, it is not possible to
>   write a class that correctly implements both the Set and List
>   interfaces.)

and

> While the Collection interface adds no stipulations to the general contract for the `Object.hashCode` method, programmers should take note that any class that overrides the `Object.equals` method must also override the `Object.hashCode` method in order to satisfy the general contract for the `Object.hashCode` method. In particular, `c1.equals(c2)` implies that `c1.hashCode()==c2.hashCode()`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question: why does it have these methods? It's done simply for convenience to be able to include Java Docs giving hints as to what implementers should do with these methods (e.g. comparing equality of values rather than references).

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other great answers.  In the Collections interface, the equals method is defined in that interface to make some decisions in the way equaling two instances of collection should work.  From the [JAVA 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html%20%20So%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20add%20methods%20from%20the%20Object%20class%20for%20any%20other%20reason%20that%20giving%20more%20%20definitiveness%20to%20the%20java%20doc.%20%20This%20is%20the%20reason%20why%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20count%20those%20methods%20in%20the%20abstract%20methods%20in%20the%20abstract%20methods%20of%20an%20interface.%20%20Also,%20in%20JAVA%208%20for%20the%20same%20reason,%20default%20methods%20from%20the%20Object%20class%20are%20not%20allowed%20and%20will%20generate%20a%20compile%20error.):

> More generally, implementations of the various Collections Framework
>   interfaces are free to take advantage of the specified behavior of
>   underlying Object methods wherever the implementor deems it
>   appropriate.

So you don’t add methods from the Object class for any other reason that giving more definitiveness to the java doc.  This is the reason why you don’t count those methods in the abstract methods in the abstract methods of an interface.

Moreover, in JAVA 8, along the same line of reasoning, default methods from the Object class are not allowed and will generate a compile error.  I believe it’s was done to prevent this type of confusion.  So if you try to create a default method called hashCode(), for example, it will not compile.

Here is a more in-depth explanation for this behavior in JAVA 8 from the [Lambda FAQ](http://www.lambdafaq.org/why-cant-default-methods-override-equals-hashcode-and-tostring/):

> An interface cannot provide a default implementation for any of the
>   methods of the Object class. This is a consequence of the “class wins”
>   rule for method resolution: a method found on the superclass chain
>   always takes precedence over any default methods that appear in any
>   superinterface. In particular, this means one cannot provide a default
>   implementation for equals, hashCode, or toString from within an
>   interface.
>
> This seems odd at first, given that some interfaces actually define
>   their equals behavior in documentation. The List interface is an
>   example. So, why not allow this?
>
> One reason is that it would become more difficult to reason about when
>   a default method is invoked. The current rules are simple: if a class
>   implements a method, that always wins over a default implementation.
>   Since all instances of interfaces are subclasses of Object, all
>   instances of interfaces have non-default implementations of equals,
>   hashCode, and toString already. Therefore, a default version of these
>   on an interface is always useless, and it may as well not compile.
>
> Another reason is that providing default implementations of these
>   methods in an interface is most likely misguided. These methods
>   perform computations over the object’s state, but the interface, in
>   general, has no access to state; only the implementing class has
>   access to this state. Therefore, the class itself should provide the
>   implementations, and default methods are unlikely to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the great answers above, it makes sense to have the 'equals' or `hashCode' methods in this scenario:

```
Collection<Whatever> list1 = getArrayList();
Collection<Whatever> list2 = getAnotherArrayList();

if(list1.equals(list2)){
    // do something
}
```

In the absence of the `equals` method in the interface, we'll be forced to use concrete types, which is generally not a good practice :

```
ArrayList<Whatever> list1 = getArrayList();
ArrayList<Whatever> list2 = getAnotherArrayList();

if(list1.equals(list2)){
    // do something
}
```